# JSZip - how to name file with generateAsync without download it

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, jszip, generate

Good morning, I am using JSZip to create a zip, I have this code:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = content[i]; i++) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file(f.name, f);
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression:"DEFLATE", compressionOptions: { level: 9 }})
    .then(function(content) {
      var item = {
        'type' : content.type,
        'size' : content.size,
        //'name' : ¿content.name?
      }
   });
}
```

I do not want to download the file, I want to upload it to my server, but it does not have an attribute name, it has two attributes: type and size. But I need to set a name to the file.
It does not work if I write 'name' : f.name, because the function is async.
Do someone know how to pass the attributte name to content.
Edit: or, if you can tell me how to make it not async, that will work too.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using this:
Use a function that calls the async method, and receive the ZIP and the name of the file.

```
function makeZip(zip, name) {
    name = name.split('.')[0] + ".zip";
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression:"DEFLATE", compressionOptions: { level: 9 }})
      .then(function(content) {
         // see FileSaver.js
         console.log(content)
         saveAs(content, name)       
         var item = {
           'name': name,
           'type': content.type,
           'size': content.size,
           'guid': generatorguid()
         };
      });
}
```

And then call it from the for:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = content[i]; i++) {
    var fZip = new JSZip();
    fZip.file(f.name, f);
    makeZip(fZip, f.name);
}
```